# java command not working

Tags: java

I have java thousand times before, but this time java command simply doesnt work as expected.
javac command runs fine, but java command opens another command window and shows java command options and then immediately disappears. the title of that new window shows its executing some java.hwd file present in the bin folder which contains all java tools for application development.
Please help. I am using jdk1.6 .

Comment: what command are you using?  What is the full command?

Comment: How about some error messages and some code ? My crystal ball is broken today. What is hwd ?

Answer (score 1):

Odds are someone put in a script with the name of `java`, `java.cmd`, `java.bat`, etc. in the path just prior to the actual java executable.  Typically such scripts contain a call to the true java command, but sometimes due to lack of specifying a fixed path, they might actually call themselves.

This script likely was meant as a wrapper around the actual java command to perhaps turn on some sort of java debugging or extra functionality.  The only problem is that either the script wasn't removed after testing, the debugging interferes with your normal operation, or the person who did this didn't take care to make his changes only affect him.